# R: Adding Footnote to table output

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I, a R beginner, created following reproducible example code that serves to output the test statistics of the ADF test for various variables:

```
library(urca)
data(nporg)
df <- nporg[complete.cases(nporg), ]

table_adf = function(x) {

  for (i in 1:x) { #something is wrong here
     out1 <- ur.df(x, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
     out2 <- ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
     out <- c(out1,out2)
     return(data.frame(matrix(out, nrow=1, dimnames=list(NULL, names(out)))))
  }

  footnote <- rep("", 3)
  footnote[1] <- c("Lag length determined with the AIC information criteria.")
  footnote[2] <- c(paste("ADF critical values drift:", out1@cval[[1]], out1@cval[[2]], out1@cval[[3]]))
  footnote[3] <- c(paste("ADF critical values trend:", out2@cval[[2]], out2@cval[[2]], out2@cval[[3]]))
  print(footnote) # something is wrong here, too
}

rbind(
  table_adf(df$emp),
  table_adf(df$cpi),
  table_adf(df$sp)
)
```

My question:
**How can I print the footnote below the table, and, if possible, also add each variable name into the row?**

If you see any other mistake or inefficiency in my code, please give me a hint. Thank you.

Update: Desired Output:

```
==============================================
                     drift          trend     
----------------------------------------------
emp                 -0.259          -4.841 ***    
cpi                  0.488          -1.326    
sp                   0.232          -3.831 **    
...                  ...            ...
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
```

I changed the numbers in trend so that you can see the significances.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, you are trying to create a table of the two estimates and add footnotes to that table?

Comment: You may try this - `table_adf = function(x) {
  out_list <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
    out1 <- ur.df(x, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
    out2 <- ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "AIC")@teststat[1]
    out <- c(out1,out2)
    out_list[i] <- list(out)
  }
  return(data.frame(matrix(out_list, nrow=1, dimnames=list(NULL, names(out)))))
}`

Answer (score 3):

### One table per variable with their own critical values

`stargazer` has great reporting functionality. Here is something you can do for example using `stargazer()`'s `notes=` argument for footnotes:

```
library(urca)
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)

data(nporg)
df <- nporg[complete.cases(nporg), ]

table_adf = function(DF, ...){
  var_list = list(...)
    select_(DF, .dots = var_list) %>%
    {invisible(Map(function(x, y){
      out1 = ur.df(x, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC")
      out2 = ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "AIC")
      est_df = data.frame(drift = out1@teststat[1], trend = out2@teststat[1],
                          row.names = y)
      footnote1 = paste("ADF critical values drift:", out1@cval[1,1], out1@cval[1,2], out1@cval[1,3])
      footnote2 = paste("ADF critical values trend:", out2@cval[1,1], out2@cval[1,2], out2@cval[1,3])
      stargazer(est_df, type = "text", summary = FALSE,
                notes = c(footnote1, footnote2))
    },. , var_list))}
}

table_adf(df, "emp", "cpi", "sp")
```

Use the `...` argument and `select_` + `.dots` instead of `select` to programmatically feed in variable names

Note that I have changed your `out1@cval`'s indexing to correctly refer to the "tau" critical values. Although I am not familiar with the ADF test, your way of indexing a 2x3 matrix with `out1@cval[[1]]` seems strange to me. So I suspect you actually wanted the first row from that table.

```
> out1@cval
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58
phi1  6.70  4.71  3.86
```

Result:

```
==============================================
                     drift          trend     
----------------------------------------------
emp                 -0.259          -3.041    
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15  

==============================================
                     drift          trend     
----------------------------------------------
cpi                  0.488          -1.326    
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15  

==============================================
                     drift          trend     
----------------------------------------------
sp                   0.232          -1.343    
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
```

### Single table with all variable estimates significance indicator

Now, this is a bit more involved, since you have to...:

1. Extract estimates (`@teststate`) from each `ur.df` object
2. See if each estimate is significant when compared to `@cval`
3. Put all estimates into the same table

Notice I used a minimal number of pipe operators `%>%` in this function since almost every step were used more than once. For example, I cannot just pipe the `...` arguments into `lapply` for `tests` because I also need the variable list to set the `row.names` in the `est_table` step.

The `var_list = as.list(unlist(list(...)))` seems unnecessarily complicated, but it is a way to allow the user to input vectors of variable names `c("emp", "cpi", "sp")`, individual variable names `"emp", "cpi", "sp"`, or both `c("emp", "cpi"), "sp"`. This creates extra convenience for the user. The `ifelse` step at the very beginning checks whether there are zero arguments for variable names, and uses the entire dataframe if it is the case.

```
table_adf = function(DF, ...){
  # Stores ... arguments as list
  var_list = as.list(unlist(list(...)))

  # Subset DF based on var_list
  if(length(var_list) == 0){
    subset = DF
    var_list = as.list(names(DF))
  }else{
    subset = select_(DF, .dots = var_list)
  }

  # Run model for each variable, and stored as list of lists, each element of the 
  # outer list contains a list of the variable's drift and trend estimates
  tests = lapply(subset, function(x, y){
    out1 = ur.df(x, type = "drift", selectlags = "AIC")
    out2 = ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "AIC")
    return(list(out1, out2))
  })

  # Store each model estimates in to a dataframe with corresponding variable names
  est_df = lapply(tests, function(x){
    data.frame(drift = x[[1]]@teststat[1], trend = x[[2]]@teststat[1])
  })

  # Combine the list into a single dataframe
  est_table = do.call(rbind, est_df)

  critical_vals = data.frame(tests[[1]][[1]]@cval[1,], 
                             tests[[1]][[2]]@cval[1,])

  # Check for significance level and add *'s accordingly
  est_table = Map(function(x, y){
    ifelse(x < y[1], paste(x, "***"), 
           ifelse(x < y[2], paste(x, "**"),
                  ifelse(x < y[3], paste(x, "*"), x)))
  }, est_table, critical_vals) %>% data.frame(row.names = unlist(var_list))

  # Set footnotes
  footnote1 = paste("ADF critical values drift:", paste(critical_vals[[1]], collapse = " "))
  footnote2 = paste("ADF critical values trend:", paste(critical_vals[[2]], collapse = " "))

  # Create nice looking table with critical values  
  stargazer(est_table, type = "text", summary = FALSE,
            notes = c(footnote1, footnote2))
}
```

Below demonstrates ways the user can input variable names to get their desired estimates:

```
> table_adf(df, "emp", "cpi", "sp")

==============================================
                     drift          trend     
----------------------------------------------
emp                 -0.259          -3.041    
cpi                  0.488          -1.326    
sp                   0.232          -1.343    
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15  

> table_adf(df, names(df)[-1])

==============================================
                     drift           trend    
----------------------------------------------
gnp.r          1.22473721812295      -1.308   
gnp.n           4.2258196600637      2.195    
gnp.pc        -0.153914521574277     -2.628   
ip             1.49350460242673      -0.924   
emp           -0.258523412908067     -3.041   
ur            -2.75061777744267 *    -2.777   
gnp.p          1.06909915298064      -0.800   
cpi            0.488243115715459     -1.326   
wg.n           2.81042091873464      0.399    
wg.r           0.399440467221402     -2.445   
M              1.45354783780152      -0.454   
vel            -2.50304919304012     -2.537   
bnd            1.21565390985417      1.837    
sp             0.231913401411228     -1.343   
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15  

> table_adf(df)

==============================================
                     drift           trend    
----------------------------------------------
year           -1.73205080756904     -1.732   
gnp.r          1.22473721812295      -1.308   
gnp.n           4.2258196600637      2.195    
gnp.pc        -0.153914521574277     -2.628   
ip             1.49350460242673      -0.924   
emp           -0.258523412908067     -3.041   
ur            -2.75061777744267 *    -2.777   
gnp.p          1.06909915298064      -0.800   
cpi            0.488243115715459     -1.326   
wg.n           2.81042091873464      0.399    
wg.r           0.399440467221402     -2.445   
M              1.45354783780152      -0.454   
vel            -2.50304919304012     -2.537   
bnd            1.21565390985417      1.837    
sp             0.231913401411228     -1.343   
----------------------------------------------
ADF critical values drift: -3.51 -2.89 -2.58  
ADF critical values trend: -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
```

Comment: Dear @useR that almost solved it. Is it possible to get the last output in "Result" into one table, listing the critical values only once below? And possibly, instead of "tau", writing the variables name into the row?

Comment: I just inserted an example of a desired output.

Comment: "So I suspect you actually wanted the first row from that table." Yes, exact. Though I have to admit that I still struggle to understand what the first four lines in the code really mean. New to dplyr..

Comment: @DanielOY Which four lines? I'm more than happy to add some explanation to make it clearer.

Comment: @DanielOY Updated my answer. Does this seem like what you are looking for?